# Jersey - Client Security and Apache HttpClient

Tags: httpclient, jersey

I am working on a jersey rest client and I am building my client and my authentication issues with this:

```
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();
Client client = Client.create(config);
client.addFilter(new HTTPBasicAuthFilter("user", "password"));
```

So why does everyone, including the jersey documentation, refer to Apache HttpClient to deal with security, when it is working like I wrote? It doesnt seem to use the Apache Framework. So why use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, this works with any Jersey client. Did anyone indicate it only works with apache? Where?

Comment: Here http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#d4e778 they just write about HttpUrlConnection and HttpClient. And some posts here indicates it as well. So was just wondering.

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. It is obsolete and predates the HttpBasicAuthFilter. We need to fix this document.

Comment: Is there an actual version for security?